# Can you force a Page Render after it's loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Problem: 
   I am loading one of several user controls based on a selected tab within RadTabstrip Control which is on the parent page. I've captured the Selected Tab and assigned it to a Session variable within the OnTabClick event to use in each User Control to determine if that particular control needs to be rendered.

The reason for this is because each User Control queries a database to render different charts and I don't want unneccesary processing occuring on every post back to the server. I'd like to add that each User Control has several Labels in their Markup that only gets the Text values assigned during runtime based on the content retrieved from the database.

When I load the main page, the selected tab variable is checked by each User Control and everything works fine from that scope. (The first tab at index 0 has no Charts)

Problem is when I select a Tab which has a User Control, the appropriate code to acquire the data from the database and build the chart works fine but the TEXT value of the Label controls in the Markup don't show up on the Page, although the TEXT values are being set in the Code-Behind at the same time the data is being retreived.

If I perform a Post Back of the same page, the TEXT values of the Label controls appear.

I believe this is because the 1st stages of the Page Life Cycle which include the rendering of the Markup aren't firing on the initial loading of the User Control, but get fired on subsequent Reloads or Refreshes of the Page.

Is there a way to work around this? I am figuring a call to the Render event after hitting the database would work but I may be way off base on my thoughts.

Can anybody provide some advice or a potential solution???

Thanks

Comment: it definitely sounds as if your user control data is being mapped to the user control labels to late.  When and how are you creating the user control?  It sounds like your doing this during the OnTabClick method which should not be a problem since user events fire before Page_PreRender() which is your last chance event to modify the page before it's sent to the client.

Comment: The UserControl's are static and already created in the site. The hierarchy is: Master Page, SubMaster Page, ASPX page, and then the UserControls which are Registered with a TagName and Prefix within the ASPX page and added in div tags to that page. When the site loads the ASPX page gets loaded and the Markup is rendered for each of the UserControls as well. If I remove the conditional check and simply allow all controls to get built, the problem doesn't occur; BUT then I have the other issue of constantly querying the DB for every UserControl on a postback. A killer for performance.

Answer (score 1):

I was never able to resolve the late binding issue which prevented the text of the labels from appearing until after a manual refresh of my page so I approached the issue from a different angle. I still retained the logic that only allowed the data of each User Control to get populated if their corresponding Tabs were selected by the user, but I moved the in-line code which was embedded in my Markup to my Code-Behind file.

I was not 100% certain as to the order that the mark-up vs. the code-behind got processed, so I researched and found that anything done declaratively in the aspx page is processed first, and the objects are created before being accessed or updated in the code behind.
So with this information I totally separated the two and was able to get the Text to render on the labels without any issue.

I still would haved liked to have known the appropriate way to force a page to call the Render event to simulate or mimick a manual Postback after the initial Page_Load, but going with the flow of the Page Cycle is the much easier and probably a more preferable way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach your problem is to consider use of the "Update Panel".  It will allow you to render the entire page and then on an event only refresh the area of the update panel.

Generally I would love this feature for performance reasons but there is a catch.  Some browsers (e.g. versions of Safari and Opera) do not render these correctly.  Is your application a web application intended for general use by consumers?  If so you may need to consider a full page refresh on the same page and pass the user data (unless Opera / other browsers have fixed this shortcoming - I have not tested in in 4 months).